# Sending mail with PHP not working with my present code

Tags: php, forms, email, contacts

I wrote this code but it isn't sending it to my email. What can be wrong?

This is the code from the contact form:

```
<!-- send mail configuration -->
<input type="hidden" value="send-mail.php" name="to" id="to" />
<input type="hidden" value="Enter the subject here" name="subject" id="subject" />
<input type="hidden" value="send-mail.php" name="sendMailUrl" id="sendMailUrl" />
<!-- ENDS send mail configuration -->
```

This is the code for the send-mail.php

```
<?php
//vars
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$to = explode(',', $_POST['to'] );

$from = $_POST['kurtfarrugia92@gmail.com'];

//data
$msg = "NAME: "  .$_POST['name']    ."<br>\n";
$msg .= "EMAIL: "  .$_POST['email']    ."<br>\n";
$msg .= "WEBSITE: "  .$_POST['web']    ."<br>\n";
$msg .= "COMMENTS: "  .$_POST['comments']    ."<br>\n";

//Headers
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers .= "From: <".$from. ">" ;


//send for each mail
foreach($to as $mail){
mail($mail, $subject, $msg, $headers);
}

?>
```

Comment: What is it doing here <input type="hidden" value="send-mail.php" name="to" id="to" /> ?

Comment: let me publish to whole form again

Comment: $from = $_POST['kurtfarrugia92@gmail.com'];
 shouldn't have the $_POST[] bit too

Comment: Form Inputs are not proper. In 'to' input field, we'll separate email addresses with comma.

Comment: The form looks wrong. If you paste the entire html form, I'm sure we can identify problem quicker. Also, in my opinion `$headers .= "From:  $from <$from>" ;` would be better

Answer (score 0):

Basic PHP mail script.

file mail.php

```
    <html>
    <body>

    <?php
    if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
    //if "email" is filled out, send email
      {
      //send email
      $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
      $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
      $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
      mail("someone@example.com", $subject,
      $message, "From:" . $email);
      echo "Thank you for using our mail form";
      }
    else
    //if "email" is not filled out, display the form
      {
      echo "<form method='post' action='mail.php'>
      Email: <input name='email' type='text'><br>
      Subject: <input name='subject' type='text'><br>
      Message:<br>
      <textarea name='message' rows='15' cols='40'>
      </textarea><br>
      <input type='submit'>
      </form>";
      }
    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have error reporting on? It may be handy to get more info about what is going on/wrong.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Try:

echo  "mail($mail, $subject, $msg, $headers)";

to see if what you are sending to mail() is exactly what you think it is.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: subject in C:\xampp\htdocs\thirdLogin\html\send-mail.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: to in C:\xampp\htdocs\thirdLogin\html\send-mail.php on line 6

    Notice: Undefined index: name in    C:\xampp\htdocs\thirdLogin\html\send-mail.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\thirdLogin\html\send-mail.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined index: web in C:\xampp\htdocs\thirdLogin\html\send-mail.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined index: comments in C:\xampp\htdocs\thirdLogin\html\send-mail.php on line 14

Comment: The form you've posted, that is your real form? Because it needs to contain all the fields you want to grab in your send-mail.php script...